# Read Gmail emails using Powershell

Tags: powershell, script, gmail

We want to automate actions based on emails we receive by email from different management systems from devices in our network

I've tried this small script, but it lists only the subject, not the body

```
# load rss-feed
$webclient = new-object System.Net.WebClient

# access the rss-feed
$webclient.Credentials = new-object System.Net.NetworkCredential ("scominbox@domain", "Password")

# download the rss as xml
[xml]$xml= $webclient.DownloadString("https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom")

# display only sender name and message title as custom table
$format= @{Expression={$_.title};Label="Title"},@{Expression={$_.author.name};Label="Author"}

# display the table
$xml.feed.entry | format-table $format
```

How can I read the emails?

Comment: All that script does is setups a RSS feed to your inbox.  If you want the body of the email that requires more work.

Comment: I know, and thats the part I'm asking for help to, because I'm not sure how to achieve that

Answer (score 2):

#### How can I read Gmail using PowerShell

You can try [Gmail.ps](https://github.com/nikoblag/Gmail.ps):

> A PowerShell module for managing your Gmail, with all the tools you'll need. Search, read and send emails, archive, mark as read/unread, delete emails, and manage labels
>
> **Features**
>
> - Read emails
> - Search emails
> - (Update) emails: label, archive, delete, mark as read/unread/spam, star
> - Manage labels
> - Move between labels/mailboxes
> - Automatic authentication, using the Windows Credential Manager

Source [Gmail.ps](https://github.com/nikoblag/Gmail.ps)

Note that I've not tested this and have no connection (pun intended) to the software.

Comment: I'll try it and update here how it went

Comment: ... sooo... how'd it go?

Answer (score 0):

```
   # load rss-feed
   $webclient = new-object System.Net.WebClient

   # access the rss-feed
   $webclient.Credentials = new-object System.Net.NetworkCredential ("username", "password")

   # download the rss as xml
   [xml]$xml= $webclient.DownloadString("https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom")

   # display only sender name and message title as custom table
   $format= @{Expression={$_.id};Label="id"},@{Expression={"|"};Label="|"},@{Expression={$_.author.email};Label="name"},@{Expression={"|"};Label="|"},@{Expression={$_.issued};Label="issued"},@{Expression={"|"};Label="|"},@{Expression={$_.summary};Label="summary"}

   # display the table
   $xml.feed.entry | format-table $format
```